# How to change location of temp files created using NPOI (.NET port of Apache POI)?

Tags: c#, npoi

While I have seen examples for changing the location of temp files (poifiles) for Apache POI through either the system temp directory or the setTempFileCreationStrategy in TempFile, I have not yet seen one for NPOI (.NET port of Apache POI)? Is there a similar solution for changing the location of temp files in NPOI without changing the system temp directory?